# Creating Base Controller for ASP.NET core to do logging but something is wrong with my constructor signature?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, dependency-injection, ilogger

I want to have an easy way to have all the web api controllers automatically log what they are doing without explicitly  tell it. Why is this incorrect ?  Also, is there any better ways ?

```
 public class BaseController<T> : ControllerBase where T: BaseController<T>
{
    private readonly IAppLogger<T> _logger;

    public BaseController(IAppLogger<T> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}

 [Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class RfReportTypeController : BaseController<RfReportTypeController>
{
    private readonly IRfReportTypeService _rfReportTypeService;

    public RfReportTypeController(IRfReportTypeService rfReportTypeService)
    {
        _rfReportTypeService = rfReportTypeService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rfReportTypeService));
    }
}
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the
>   required formal parameter 'logger' of
>   `BaseController<RfReportTypeController>.BaseController(IAppLogger<RfReportTypeController>)`   PWDRS.WebAPI    C:\Users\M3MAH02\source\repos\PWDRS\PWDRS\PWDRS.WebAPI\Controllers\RfReportTypeController.cs    17  Active

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to pass parameters required by base constructor

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class RfReportTypeController : BaseController<RfReportTypeController>
{
    private readonly IRfReportTypeService _rfReportTypeService;

    public RfReportTypeController(
        IRfReportTypeService rfReportTypeService, 
        IAppLogger<RfReportTypeController> logger //<--NOTE THIS
    ) : base(logger) //<-- NOTE THIS
    {
        _rfReportTypeService = rfReportTypeService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rfReportTypeService));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer would make all of your controllers tightly coupled with the logger and will diminish the purpose of having a Base Controller. I would propose the following solution

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public abstract class BaseController<T> : ControllerBase
{
    private IAppLogger<T> _logger;
    protected IAppLogger<T> Logger=> _logger ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IAppLogger<T>>();
}

public class RfReportTypeController : BaseController<RfReportTypeController>
{
    private readonly IRfReportTypeService _rfReportTypeService;

    public RfReportTypeController(IRfReportTypeService rfReportTypeService)
    {
        _rfReportTypeService = rfReportTypeService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rfReportTypeService));
    }
}
```

Comment: The [Route()] and [ApiController] attributes should not be put on the BaseController since this will not be longer the routing point. This base controller will be inherited with different api controllers and where they are the one to used [Route()] and [ApiController] attributes. Please check my posted answer above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In response to @Mohamed Salman's answer:
The [Route()] and [ApiController] attributes should not be put on the BaseController since this will not be longer the routing point. This base controller will be inherited with different api controllers and where they are the one to used [Route()] and [ApiController] attributes.

Please check the new modified sample source below:

```
public abstract class BaseController<T> : ControllerBase
{
    private IAppLogger<T> _logger;
    protected IAppLogger<T> Logger=> _logger ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IAppLogger<T>>();
}


[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class RfReportTypeController : BaseController<RfReportTypeController>
{
    private readonly IRfReportTypeService _rfReportTypeService;

    public RfReportTypeController(IRfReportTypeService rfReportTypeService)
    {
        _rfReportTypeService = rfReportTypeService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rfReportTypeService));
    }
}
```